# How to make a switch parameter work with 'valuefrompipelinebypropertyname'?

Tags: powershell, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing

I am building a function. At times, I want to be able to provide parameter inputs for the function via the pipeline, because often the values are found on a csv file:

```
$CsvData = @"
Label,Key, IsSubTrigger
Function10,f10, 0
Function11,f11, 1
Function12,f12, true
Function13,f13, false
"@ |ConvertFrom-Csv
```

The following is the bare bones function:

```
Function foo{
     [CmdletBinding()]
     Param(
        [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string]$Label,
        [parameter(valuefrompipelinebypropertyname)]
        [string]$key,
        [parameter(valuefrompipelinebypropertyname)]
        [switch]$IsSubTrigger,
        
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string]$Path
     )

     Process{
        "Label:" + $Label,
        "key: " + $Key,
        "IsSubTrigger: " + $IsSubTrigger
     }
}
```

Invoking `$CsvData | foo` outputs an error for each csv row:

```
foo: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'IsSubTrigger'. Cannot convert value "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter". Boolean parameters accept only Boolean values and numbers, such as $True, $False, 1 or 0.
```

I have tried solving this but but have sadly gotten nowhere.

Comment: Question: are the values in `IsSubTrigger` on the CSV are always either `1`, `0`, `true` and `false`? You should first convert $csvdata into a `psobjecty`

Comment: I follow your suggestion but I dont quite understand how would a `psObject` convert a string `"1"`/`"true"` into a bool type. Hmm I will give it ago and see though. Thank you.

Comment: `Import-Csv` and `ConvertFrom-Csv` already outputs `psobject` so that suggestion doesn't help.

Comment: Sorry, my suggestion was poorly phrased. What I did mean is appending ` | ForEach-Object { $_.IsSubTrigger = ($_.IsSubTrigger -iin '1', 'true'); $_ }` to the CSV import cmdlet. Thus forcing `IsSubTrigger` to be a boolean, which can be parsed by the function. Of course this requires knowing in advance what values will be present in the field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell doesn't know how to properly coerce a `string` into a [`SwitchParameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.switchparameter?view=powershellsdk-7.4.0), which leads to the issue you're observing:

```bash
[switch] 'true'
# InvalidArgument: Cannot convert the "true" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter".
```

What you can do to help it, is create an argument transformation class, essentially a class that inherits from [`ArgumentTransformationAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.argumenttransformationattribute?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0), that handles the logic for converting a `string` into a `bool`, then that `bool` can be coerced into `SwitchParameter` without issues later on:

```bash
class BoolParseTransformation : System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTransformationAttribute {
    [Object] Transform([System.Management.Automation.EngineIntrinsics] $engineIntrinsics, [Object] $inputData) {
        $int = 0
        if ([int]::TryParse($inputData, [ref] $int)) {
            return [bool] $int
        }

        return [bool]::Parse($inputData)
    }
}
```

Then in your `param` block, you can implement it like this:

```bash
function foo {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string] $Label,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string] $key,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [BoolParseTransformation()]
        [switch] $IsSubTrigger,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string] $Path
    )
    
    process { $PSBoundParameters }
}
```

Comment: I would have never figured out this elegant solution, thank you Santiago!